# Split a string based on "^" in R

Tags: r, string, stringr, stringi

I need to split and obtain the all the characters before `^`

example:
I have a column in a dataframe that reads

```
2567543^ABC 
7545435^J 
8934939^XY
```

and the result column in the same dataframe should read:

```
2567543
7545435
8934939
```

I tried using `stringr`, `strsub{base}`, `stringi`, `gsubfn`.  But they are throwing weird results because `^`.  I cannot replace `^` because the table is simply huge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove all the chars from `^` upto the last  using `sub` function. Since `^` is a special meta charcater in regex which matches the start of a line, you need to escape `^` symbol in-order to match a literal `^` symbol.

```
sub("\\^.*", "", df$x)
```

**Example:**

```
> df <- data.frame(x=c("2567543^ABC", "7545435^J", "8934939^XY"))
> df$x <- sub("\\^.*", "", df$x)
> df
        x
1 2567543
2 7545435
3 8934939
```

**OR**

```
> df <- data.frame(x=c("2567543^ABC", "7545435^J", "8934939^XY"))
> df$x <- strsplit(as.character(df$x), "\\^")[[1]][1]
> df
        x
1 2567543
2 2567543
3 2567543
```

**OR**

Use `fixed=TRUE` parameter in strsplit since `^` is a special character.

```
> df <- data.frame(x=c("2567543^ABC", "7545435^J", "8934939^XY"))
> df$x <- strsplit(as.character(df$x), "^", fixed=TRUE)[[1]][1]
> df
        x
1 2567543
2 2567543
3 2567543
```

Comment: Id all digits you could use `gsub("\\D", "", df[["x"]])` too.